# How to make WinInet HTTPS subsequent requests to reuse connection?

Tags: winapi, wininet

I'm sending a few subsequent http-requests on my server using wininet, and until I use TLS (`INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE` flag in `HttpOpenRequestA`) the connection is being reused ok. Now I want to use TLS, set the mentioned flag, and  also flags `INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID` and `INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID` (to skip self-signed cert verification) - now a new connection is established for every `HttpOpenRequest` call. How to reuse conn with tls?

p.s. `INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT` has no effect

Comment: p.s. INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT has no effect

Comment: that info belongs in your question, not in a comment. Please [edit] your question

Answer (score 0):

Each new connection does a separate TCP handshake and a separate TLS handshake.In case of session reuse no key exchange is performed, that is the same symmetric key is re-used.

See [**How does SSL/TLS work?**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work)